# Printing via wifi

Tags: android, printing

I want to print a bitmap. I am using PrintHelper. It shows a print dialog in between. Is there a method to accomplish it without the print dialog displaying? Or throught the printer IP and port? As this is the requirement.

Comment: what printer are u used

Comment: wifi printer...HP